# Xcode: Compile Error 71, can't find copystrings

Tags: xcode

```
CopyStringsFile ../StepMania.app/Contents/Resources/it.lproj/Localizable.strings it.lproj/Localizable.strings
cd ~/OpenSource/GameDev/StepMania/PBProject
setenv ICONV /usr/bin/iconv
/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/CoreBuildTasks.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/copystrings --validate --inputencoding utf-16 --outputencoding UTF-16 it.lproj/Localizable.strings --outdir ~/OpenSource/GameDev/StepMania/PBProject/../StepMania.app/Contents/Resources/it.lproj

error: can't exec '/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/CoreBuildTasks.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/copystrings' (No such file or directory)
Command /Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/CoreBuildTasks.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/copystrings failed with exit code 71
```

But when I navigate to that location, I have the file (copystrings).

Anybody have any solutions?
Using Xcode 3.2.3 (Latest)
Mac OS X 10.6.4

I'm also using the latest SVN of StepMania, if you want to look at the localization files.
https://svn.stepmania.com/svn/trunk/stepmania/PBProject/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had on old symlink to ruby. I originally thought this wasn't related to ruby... but as it turns out.. it is.

sudo ln -s /opt/local/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby

Make sure to delete the old /usr/bin/ruby first.